# How to put text templates into the color box theorem environment?

Tags: tcolorbox, answers

### Problem Statement

I have been received an error message of

`! Argument of \begin has an extra }.`

regarding to line 28 (i.e. `\begin{exref}`) of the MWE. Which this is an optional environment to state the source of the exercise.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{TDsolution}

\definecolor{color00}{HTML}{9B9B9B}

\newcommand\chapterbackcolor{color00}
\renewcommand\chapterbackcolor{color00}

\usepackage[listings,theorems,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

% THEOREM STYLE ======================================
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks}
\usepackage[amsmath,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\newtcbtheorem{ex}{Exercise}{%
before lower app={\noindent\ignorespaces Solution: \\},
fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,fontupper=\sffamily,
colframe=\chapterbackcolor!75!black!50!,colback=\chapterbackcolor!15!white,
colbacktitle=\chapterbackcolor!75!black!50!,coltitle=white}{ex}
\newenvironment{exref}{\noindent\ignorespaces This question is sourced from}{\par\noindent%
\ignorespacesafterend\\}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Dummy Chapter}
\begin{ex}{Dummy Variables}
\begin{exref}
the...
\end{exref}
\begin{sol}
Let...
\tcblower
Let... 
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PaulGaborit Please put your comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ex` environment needs **two** mandatory parameters (cf. p.328, tcolorbox manual).